# Can I interact with background software?

Tags: microsoft-word, vlc-media-player, lua

I am using Unified Remote to run windows commands from my phone. Example start program, close program, fullscreen VLC, pretty much anything you can think of. It runs via a server installed on the PC, and code language is based on Lua.

I am looking for a way that I could be in an other program and pause or interact with (for instance) VLC without switching to the media player. For instance playing a game while listening to music and using my phone to change songs song without having to alt-tab out of the game. Could work as well for not changing from a Word document.

In the example of VLC, changing next track is just a case of sending the key press 'n', so essentially I want to know if I can interact like that with running software, without that software taking focus.